# On the upper bound for $|\zeta(s)|$ near the zeta zeros

Tags: cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

Let $T \in \mathbb{R}$ be large and $\rho$ be a non-trivial zero of the Riemann zeta function. Assume that $|\rho|=|\rho_T| \approx T$ and let $\varepsilon_T \approx \frac{\log \log T}{\log T}$. Is it true that

$$|\zeta(1-\rho_T + \varepsilon_T)|=o(1)$$

uniformly for $T \geq T_0$?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If $\rho_T$ is a zero of $\zeta(s)$, so is $1-\rho_T$ by the functional equation, and $|1-\rho_T|\approx T$ (depending on what you mean by $\approx$), so the $1-\ldots$ is superfluous.

A Taylor expansion of $\zeta(s)$ at $\rho_T$ gives
$$
\zeta(\rho_T+\epsilon)=\zeta^\prime(\rho_T)\cdot \epsilon+O(\epsilon)^2.
$$
Even assuming the Riemann Hypothesis, all that is known is that
$$
\zeta^\prime(\rho_T)=O(T^{\epsilon^\prime})
$$
for any $\epsilon^\prime$ (via Lindelof and the Cauchy Integral Formula for derivatives), so there's not much hope for a uniform bound.

---

Edit:  I'm expanding on DavidFarmer's comment below.  Selberg proved that for $E\subset \mathbb R$, we have that the limit as $T\to\infty$ of
$$
\frac{1}{T}\,\mu(T\le t\le 2T\,|\,\log|\zeta(1/2+i t)|/(1/2\log\log t)^{1/2}\in E)
$$
where $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure, is equal to the integral over $E$ of a Gaussian Random Variable with mean $0$ and standard deviation $1$:
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_E \exp(-x^2/2)\, dx.
$$
which is the basis for David's comment that $|\zeta(1/2+it)|$ is equal $1$ "on average".  Since the count of zeros up to height $T$ is $\sim T/(2\pi)\log(T)$, at height $T$ the average spacing between zeros is $2\pi/\log(T)$.  So the Hardy function $Z(t)$ is like $\sin(t \log(T)/2)$ near height $T$, and it's derivative has a multiplier of $\log(T)$.

Comment: Since the typical gap between zeros is $1/\log(T)$, you should expect that $\zeta'(\rho_T)$ is typically of size at least $\log(T)$.  Therefore one should expect the displayed formula in the question to typically be of size at least $\log\log T$.  It might be smaller or larger at a particular zero, but it is not plausible that it is bounded, much less that it is $o(1)$.

Comment: @DavidFarmer Can you expand on the comment "Since the typical gap...you should expect..."?

Comment: The zeta function is 1 on average, and its zeros are spaced on the scale of $1/\log(T)$ apart.  So it is like $\sin(x \log(T))$, which has derivative $\log(T)$ at its zeros.  I was just trying to give a flavor of the general principle that each derivative magnifies the function on average by a factor of $\log(T)$.